# Square Gem Loading Issue

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv, square

Not sure if this is a `square` `gem` issue or a loading issue of the `gem`, but I'm finding it on two operating systems.  How can I get this to work?  The gem seems to have a loading issue or a class issue.

`Mac OS` (`El Capitan`): `Ruby 2.5.1`, `Ruby 2.6.5`, `Ruby 2.7.0`
`CentOS 7`: `Ruby 2.5.1`

I'm using `rbenv` and the `square` gem is being shown as being loaded:

```
require 'rubygems'
Gem::Specification.sort_by{ |g| [g.name.downcase, g.version] }.group_by{ |g| g.name }
```

Here is my remedial `Ruby` script:

```
require 'square'

$sandbox_application_id      = 'sandbox-app_id_here'
$sandbox_access_token        = 'sandbox_access_token_here'

square = Square::Client.new(access_token: $sandbox_access_token)
```

The error:

```
square.rb:6:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Square::Client (NameError)
```

Support staff at `square` say they can get this to work with `Ruby 2.4.1` just fine.  This `gem` is not a year old.

How can I test this, given the current error?

Answer (score 1):

Solved:  `gem 'square.rb'` and not `gem 'square'`.

Also, uninstalling `faraday` and `bundle` afterwards, refreshes that `gem`.